# getting json data with angularjs and ionic Error

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have small JSON data from server and wanted to show in html file. unfortunately not working. Any idea?
I have invested couple of hours to find these. but still not found.. :(
Thanks for your feedback.

JS File:

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('myreddit', ['ionic']);

app.controller('RedditCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.conditions = [];

  $http.get('http://50wave.com/deesh.json')
    .success(function(response) {
      angular.forEach(response.ht, function(child) {
        $scope.stories.push(child);
      });
    });

});

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});

}());
```

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myreddit" ng-controller="RedditCtrl">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">FootBall</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <div class="list">           
          <div ng-repeat="condition in conditions">
            {{conditions.name}}
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: `unfortunately not working` is not a proper problem description. Be far more specific and isolate what is or isn't working and what troubleshooting steps you have tried and what you are seeing in browser console

Answer (score 0):

There might be more issues with your application, you did not provide enough data to troubleshoot, but from the code you have posted I see at least these 2:

1 you are pushing to `stories` array, which doesn't seem to be read in your application. I think it should be:

```
$http.get('http://50wave.com/deesh.json')
.success(function(response) {
  angular.forEach(response.ht, function(child) {
    $scope.conditions.push(child);
  });
});
```

2 when inside ng-repeat cycle, you should be addressing the item, not the collection, so not `{{conditions.name}}` but `{{condition.name}}`, so the code should be:

```
<div ng-repeat="condition in conditions">
        {{condition.name}}
</div>
```